# Pandas concat not adding rows after the first loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-multithreading, obsidian

I have functions.py file that is executed every time my main.py file is run:

```
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
from move import move_to_obsidian

pd.options.mode.copy_on_write = False

OBSIDIAN_MD_PATH = "D://Gdrive//ObsidianVault//WatsonFrames//duzeltme1.md"
OBSIDIAN_PROCESSED_PATH = 'reports/4back_to_obsidian.md'

def time_formatting(df):
    
    df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'], format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S", errors="ignore")
    df['stop'] = pd.to_datetime(df['stop'], format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S", errors="ignore")


def get_logs_from_obsidian():
    
    df = pd.read_table(OBSIDIAN_MD_PATH, 
                       index_col=0, sep="|")
    
    df = df.iloc[1: , :]
    
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    
    try: df = df.drop('    ', axis=1)    
    except: pass
         
    try: df = df.dropna(axis=1)
    except: pass
    
    try: 
        for i in range(0, 100, 1):
            if 'Unnamed ' in df.columns[i]:
                print(True)
                df = df.drop(df.columns[i], axis=1)
    except:
        pass
    
    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
    
    time_formatting(df=df)
    
    # print('-----Obsidian-----')
    # print(df['start'].tail(2), '//', '\n', df['stop'].tail(2))
    df.to_csv('reports/1obsidianlogs.csv', index=False)
    df.to_html('reports/1obsidianlogs.html')
    print('-----Obsidian-----' + '\n')
    
    return df

# get_logs_from_obsidian()


def get_logs_from_watson():
    subprocess.run(["watson", "log", "--all", "-s", ">", "D:/AUIVVII/Udemy/Inspired/Mildew/new_report.csv"], shell=True)

    df = pd.read_csv("new_report.csv")
    
    df['notes'] = ' - '

    df['id'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: f"[[WatsonFrames/ids/{x}]]")
    
    time_formatting(df)

    df1 = df.tail(1)
        
    df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    
    df1.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
    
    # print('-----Watson-----')
    # print(df1.tail(2))
    df.to_csv('reports/2watson_notcut_logs.csv')
    df1.to_csv('reports/2watsonlogs.csv', index=False)
    df1.to_html('reports/2watsonlogs.html')
    print('-----Watson-----')
    
    return df1

# get_logs_from_watson()
    

def concatting_two_dfs(first_df=get_logs_from_obsidian(), appended_df=get_logs_from_watson()):
    
    result = pd.concat([first_df, appended_df], axis=0)

    result.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    
    result.to_html('reports/3concatting_two_dfs.html')
    
    print(result.tail(5))

    return result

# concatting_two_dfs()


def back_to_md(df=concatting_two_dfs(), buf=OBSIDIAN_PROCESSED_PATH):
    
    df.to_markdown(index=False, buf=buf)
    df.to_html(index=False, buf='reports/4back_to_obsidian.html')
    
    done = print(f'---- Result can be viewed in {buf} ----')
    
    return done


def main():
    back_to_md()
    move_to_obsidian()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and here is the main.py:

```
import sys
import time

import json
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

import subprocess

def exec_main():
    from functions import main
    from backup import aws_backup
    
    time.sleep(2)
    aws_backup()
    time.sleep(1)
    main()
    time.sleep(2)
    aws_backup()

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
  def on_modified(self, event):
    if event.is_directory:
        return

    if event.src_path.endswith("frames"):
        with open(event.src_path, "r") as file:
            frames = json.load(file)
            print(f"New entries in frames.json: {frames[-1]}")
            print('Waiting a few sec for logs to be created')
            time.sleep(3)
            exec_main()
            # Perform your desired action here

if __name__ == "__main__":
  path = "C://Users//sarpy//AppData//Roaming//watson"
  event_handler = MyHandler()
  observer = Observer()
  observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False)
  observer.start()
  print('Observer started')

  try:
      while True:
          time.sleep(1)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
      observer.stop()

  observer.join()
```

[Example row to append:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKecw.png)

It concats the two pandas dataframes correctly the first time it is created, however after the first time, it is not reliable anymore and won't often work.
Both dataframes are in same format and concat works fine if it's not run on loop. However I am going to schedule this to run every time my computer opens and forget about it.
I've also added bunch of time.sleep() to see if it was logs not being created in time but that's not the case

Comment: You are running concatting_two_dfs() twice, once in main and once when running back_to_md. Also, back_to_md is not using df.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, thanks! So I did some tinkering and noticed that the second time the exec_main() was called, main() function did not call the functions that called the newer versions of my dataframe so it just doesn't return anything new. How can I prevent that?